# Java | How to determine if a calendar object is a year old?

Tags: java, calendar

If I have a calendar object with a date of 1/8/2012, how would I determine if it has been at least one year since the object's creation?

Comment: Made an edit, meant to be object, not account.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes have been supplanted by the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). If you really want .Calendar, search any of the hundreds of existing such questions already posted on StackOverflow.

Here is some example code in java.time. The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value without time-of-day or time zone. But note that determining today’s date requires a time zone.

```java
// Then.
LocalDate then = LocalDate.parse ( "2012-01-08" );

// Now.
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( zoneId );

// Elapsed.
Period period = Period.between ( then , today );
int years = period.getYears ();

// Business logic.
Boolean atLeastOneYearHasPassed = ( years >= 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "From then: " + then + " to today: " + today + ", atLeastOneYearHasPassed: " + atLeastOneYearHasPassed + ", years: " + years );
```

When run.

> From then: 2012-01-08 to today: 2015-10-17, atLeastOneYearHasPassed: true, years: 3

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need two datestamps; one for the account creation date, and the second one for "now".

Then you simply turn the two datestamps into scalar values with the same units (e.g. using `Calendar.getTime()` gives you milliseconds since some "epoch"), subtract one from the other, see if the difference is more, less or equal to 1 year == 365 days (in the relevant units).

If you are talking about "calendar years" (e.g. taking account of leap years, etcetera) then it gets more complicated, and the rules are potentially locale specific.

---

I recommend that you use the `java.time` classes rather than the old `Calendar` API.  If you are new to this, start by reading the Oracle Java tutorial ["Lesson: Date-Time Overview"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/)

Comment: Do you happen to know the syntax for this? I'm not familiar with the Calendar object at all. If we're just going to use 365 days and not worry about leap years and such.

Comment: You have lost me.  A `Calendar` object does not encode >>any<< syntax.  The syntax is in the string representation of the date, and it disappears when you create the `Calendar` object from it.  That also applies to other Java classes for representing date / time values.